# VB.NET Get String Betwen Two Strings - Not Working With Escaped Chars

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to find a string inbetween two other strings. This function is working fine but as soon as I use escaped characters ("") it stops working and a runtime error occurs. Function & working / non-working examples below:

Function:

```
Public Function GetBetween(ByVal haystack As String, ByVal needle As String, ByVal needle_two As String) As String
    Dim istart As Integer = InStr(haystack, needle)
    If istart > 0 Then
        Dim istop As Integer = InStr(istart, haystack, needle_two)
        If istop > 0 Then
            Dim value As String = haystack.Substring(istart + Len(needle) - 1, istop - istart - Len(needle))
            Return value
        End If
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Example working:

```
Dim Haystack As String = "hello find me world"
    Dim FindIt As String = GetBetween(Haystack, "hello", "world")
    MessageBox.Show(FindIt)
```

Example non-working (Using escaped """ Chars):

```
Dim Haystack As String = "<input type=""hidden"" name=""testsubmit"" id=""testsubmit"" value=""findme""  />"
    Dim FindIt As String = GetBetween(Haystack, "id=""testsubmit"" value=""", """")
    MessageBox.Show(FindIt)
```

Error:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

So basically my function is not allowing me to use it when searching for escaped chars.

Comment: If I were you I'd assume that something else broke. Once your program is compiled there is no way to tell how the string was written. Escapes only matter to the compiler, so you cannot write an algorithm that functions differently depending on how you give the strings.

Comment: Even hard coding the strings into VB before compiling such as the example in my opening Q will not function correctly which is why I opened the question. The problem can only be in the code provided as this is all that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily determine that the problem has nothing to do with escaped quotes by replacing them in your string with some other character and seeing that the function call fails in exactly the same way.

The real difference between your two test strings is that in your first example, your `needle_two` string does *not* appear in your `needle` string, while in your second example it *does*. In other words, your problem is that you start looking for `needle_two` where `needle` *begins* rather than where it ends, and `istop` ends up inside of `needle`.

What you need to do is start searching after `needle` stops:

```
Dim istop As Integer = InStr(istart + Len(needle), haystack, needle_two)
```